# Javascript condition to an alert

Tags: javascript, alert, conditional-statements

```
<script>
    var name, address, city, state, zip, birthdate , social, response1, info; 

    //Function call - vitalinfo prompts user 7 times
    function vitalinfo() {

name = window.prompt("Please enter your name", "Example: Jane Doe");

address = window.prompt("Please enter your address", "Example: 123 Main St");

city = window.prompt("Please enter your city","Example: Punxsutawney");

state = window.prompt("Please enter your state", "Example: Pennsylvania");

zip = window.prompt("Please enter your zip","Example: 12345");

birthdate = window.prompt("Please enter your birthdate","12-29-1987");

social = window.prompt("Please enter your social security number","123-45-6789"); 

//end prompts

vitalinfo= window.confirm("Do you want to review the information you entered?");

if (vitalinfo == true)
 {
window.alert (
        "Your name is " + name + "\n" + 

        "Your address is " + address + "\n" +

        "Your city is " + city + "\n" +

        "Your state is " + state + "\n" +

        "Your zip is " + state + "\n" +

        "Your birth date is " + birthdate + "\n" +

        "Your social security number is " + social);
}
```

}

I'd like to have conditions in my js so that if the name, address, zip etc variable returns null, it is blank or excluded completely from the alert. I don't know where to start.

Comment: A quick Google search yielded [this tutorial](http://referencedesigner.com/tutorials/js/js_1.php), however, since you want the to get to the point, you may want to [start here](http://referencedesigner.com/tutorials/js/js_6.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can first build your string using if statements, then alert it, or use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which acts as an inline if:

```
window.alert (
    (name ? "Your name is " + name + "\n" : '') + 
    (address ? "Your address is " + address + "\n" : '') // + etc.
);
```

This will work unless you want the values to display even if they're `''`, `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0` or `NaN`.